# Why did Roomba delete this question today?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I posted [Where can I find a map of all the canal boat routes in Bangkok?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158333/1810) in July 2020. No upvotes, no downvotes, no answers at the time of the deletion. Why did Roomba delete it today (2023-01-07)?

---

Question:  [Where can I find a map of all the canal boat routes in Bangkok?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158333/1810)

> I read on
> https://www.hotels.com/go/thailand/bangkok-river-boats-ferries#Canal_boats
> ([mirror](https://archive.vn/Wabb3)):
>
> > These **large, loud, spluttering canal boats can be found chugging up and down Bangkok's many canals**. The city's largest khlong (canal)
> > is [Saen Seab Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep),
> > which dissects Bangkok from the Old City in the west to Ramkamheng in
> > the far east.
> >
> > Canal taxi boats have exclusive use of this large artery of water,
> > which means traffic is never a problem. The frequency of these boats
> > changes throughout the day, generally ranging from 5 to 20 minutes
> > between vessels. One journey costs between 9 baht and 19 baht
> > depending on the distance.
> >
> > In the early mornings and late afternoons, these canal boats are a
> > vital transport link for office workers travelling from downtown
> > Bangkok to the eastern suburbs. Seating becomes scarce around these
> > times, but it offers an intriguing glimpse into the locals' daily
> > routine in the urban jungle.
>
> Where can I find a map of all the [canal
> boat](https://www.hotels.com/go/thailand/bangkok-river-boats-ferries#Canal_boats)
> routes (ideally with their stops) in Bangkok?
>
> The only map I could find is for the [Khlong Saen Saep boat
> service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep_boat_service),
> which operates on the [Khlong Saen
> Saep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep) canal:
>
> [image]
>
> ([image
> source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bangkok-saensaep-map.svg))
>
> ---
>
> Note that canal boats aren't the same as [river boats or river
> ferries](https://www.hotels.com/go/thailand/bangkok-river-boats-ferries#Express_Boat_river_taxis)
> ([mirror](https://archive.vn/Wabb3)).
>
> This is a canal boat:
>
> [image]

Answer (score 4):

The criteria can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) but in short it had been there for a year without upvotes, without an answer, and a general absence of other activity.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why the question wasn't deleted in July 2021?

Comment: Sorry, no. There does not seem to have been any activity on it but the timeline does not show views.

Comment: With 430 views now, it means that it didn't satisfy the view count requirement in July 2021.